# CommondInvokationFailure In Unity: Failed to build apk

Tags: exception, apk, unity-game-engine, build-error

Please stack overflow respected folks help me. I am stuck in this problem and can't fix it...

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to build apk. C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin\java.exe -Xmx2048M -Dcom.android.sdkmanager.toolsdir="D:/Asghar Jatoi/android-sdks\tools" -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -jar "D:\Dlux Gaming + Mlay Games\Unity 5.6.0\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer/Tools\sdktools.jar" -

stderr[ Error: No such file or directory 'C:/Users/shanti007/Desktop/isizwar/isizwar.keystore' ] stdout[

] exit code: 255 UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSDKTools.RunCommandInternal (System.String javaExe, System.String sdkToolsDir, System.String[] sdkToolCommand, Int32 memoryMB, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSDKTools.RunCommandSafe (System.String javaExe, System.String sdkToolsDir, System.String[] sdkToolCommand, Int32 memoryMB, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()
```

Comment: Seem like the problem is: 
`Error: No such file or directory 'C:/Users/shanti007/Desktop/isizwar/isizwar.keystore'`. Can you check that that file exists?

Comment: mayo yesterday Thanks it helped me

Comment: Nice! Sometimes an error log can be overwhelming, but it is worth it trying to understand it. At the end another developer (ie, Human) wrote the code that prints the error and the related info ;)

Comment: I was getting same error, But it simply solved by browsing and adding same key store again.